# Viber on Android - transfer backup from Huawei to Samsung phone

Tags: samsung, huawei, viber-messenger

on my old Huawei phone I backed up Viber data (chat history and media) via Viber's Settings/Account/Backup feature. On Huawei there was only the option to backup to Huawei cloud (no option to backup to Google Drive).

Now, I have installed Viber on my other phone (Samsung S21) and there is no restore option in Viber because it is only expecting the backup to be on Google Drive.

Is there any way I can transfer this manually?